# result compile is "INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS"

Tags: android, azure, android-studio, signalr

I am trying to run my app on Android Studio 3.5.2.

Launching 'app' on samsung SM-A105M.

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS
Installation failed due to: 'null'
```

Retry

Implemented SignalR for example [SignalR_with_Android](https://www.tahasivaci.com/android/android-signalr-chat-with-c-and-web-api) 
add 2 librarys `jar`

but not compile

Answer (score 0):

I think we need more details to know for sure.

Do the jar files you are including have native dependencies?  If so, do you know what ABIs (libs subfolders) they supply?

Do those ABIs align to the ABIs you defined in your Gradle script?

Do you have a split / flavor for arm64-v8a?

ABI refers to (basically) the chipset(s) you are targeting in you application.  For example, if you are building an app for armeabi-v7a (32 bit "modern" arm) and trying to deploy it to an x86 or x86_64 device (a 32 bit or 64 bit intel emulator), you will receive this error.

Are you building / deploying an APK or bundle?

arm64-v8a (64 bit arm devices like your A10) tend to be backwards compatible with  armeabi-v7a (32 bit arm) apps but if you're using Google's new bundling method it may be complaining because you did not provide a split for 64 bit arm.

There are other scenarios where splits don't match device characteristics (screen density / language being the most common) but your error clearly calls out ABI (chipset compatibility).